# 3D plotting in silverlight?

Tags: function, silverlight-4.0, 3d, plot, silverlight-5.0

Is there an easy way to plot 3D functions using Silverlight 4 or 5?

The most useful thing I found was [this link](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2011/04/13/Silverlight-50-Plotting-beautiful-3D-functions.aspx), but even so it was way over my head.

I would like to just be able to input the 3D function and get a 3d plot of it.

Any ideas?

Other stuff I found was this:

[Silverlight 5 demos](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=VisualStudioVersion&f%5B0%5D.Value=10.0&f%5B0%5D.Text=Visual%20Studio%202010&f%5B1%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B1%5D.Value=Silverlight&f%5B2%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B2%5D.Value=C#&f%5B2%5D.Text=C#&f%5B3%5D.Type=Technology&f%5B3%5D.Value=Silverlight%205)

Comment: +1 for the cool links. I did that sort of plotting on an Atari 400 in my youth (really showing my age now). Will be interested in the answers you get.